# Autoscaling for ECS EC2 standalone tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, autoscaling

I am using CDK to run standalone containerized ECS tasks on EC2.

I'm not using ECS service, because my task should be triggered using a request (in this a lambda), so they are not long running (or aways on). I use the following code, which works for one instance of the task:

```js
    this.autoScalingGroup = new autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup(this, 'ASG', {
          vpc: this.vpc,
          instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(
            ec2.InstanceClass.C5,
            ec2.InstanceSize.XLARGE,
          ),
          machineImage: ecs.EcsOptimizedImage.amazonLinux2(),
          minCapacity: 1,
          maxCapacity: 10,
          updatePolicy: UpdatePolicy.rollingUpdate(),
        });
        
        const capacityProvider = new ecs.AsgCapacityProvider(
          this,
          'AsgCapacityProvider',
          {
            autoScalingGroup: this.autoScalingGroup,
          },
        );
        this.cluster.addAsgCapacityProvider(capacityProvider);
```

The problem is that I cannot run concurrent instances. So, it doesn't scale up to more instances. It only runs one instance (my container takes up ~80% of the EC2 instance resources). How would I trigger autoscaling such that when multiple tasks are run more instances get added?

p.s. obviosuly if I set `minCapacity` to x, x number of concurrent tasks can run, but I'd like to only keep 1 instance up and scale up and down.

Comment: Thanks @fedonev, would it work with ecs tasks or is it only for services? I've tried `this.autoScalingGroup.scaleOnCpuUtilization('KeepSpareCPU', {targetUtilizationPercent: 20,});` but instead of launching a new instance, I get `RESOURCE:CPU` error on additional tasks

Answer (score 2):

The CDK-created capacity provider will [auto-scale the instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cluster-auto-scaling.html) based on standalone task activity.  I suspect scaling is not working for you because your `run-task` invocations are missing a [capacity provider strategy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cluster-capacity-providers.html#capacity-providers-concepts) that tells ECS what capacity provider to use.  There are a couple of ways to fix this:

**Option 1:** Set a strategy in the [run-task](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/2.1.30/reference/ecs/run-task.html) call:

```bash
aws ecs run-task \
--cluster  <cluster-arn> \
--task-definition <task-definition-name> \
--capacity-provider-strategy capacityProvider=<capacity-provider-name>,weight=1,base=1 \
--count 3 \
```

**Option 2:** Set the cluster's *default* capacity provider strategy

The CDK's L2 `Cluster` construct does not set a default capacity provider strategy on your cluster.  See this [github issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/15230) for context and workarounds.  The default can also be set in the console.